# SQL syntax error: near "("

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, derived-table

When I try to run this query:

```
select branch_no, max (avg_salary)
from (select allocatedto, avg (salary)
      from staff, worker
      where staff.staff_no = worker.staff_no
      group by allocatedto) 
      as branch_avg (branch_no, avg_salary);
```

I get this error:

```
Error: near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: Lots of issues with that query.  Maybe sample data, table structure and desired results would help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select my_alias1,my_alias2 from (select col1,col2,...) as A (my_alias1,my_alias2)
```

The above syntax is valid in `SQL Server`.

To alias the column in derived table you need to use `AS` inside the derived table. Try this

```
SELECT Max (avg_salary)
FROM   (SELECT allocatedto  AS branch_no,
               Avg (salary) AS avg_salary
        FROM   staff
               INNER JOIN worker
                       ON staff.staff_no = worker.staff_no
        GROUP  BY allocatedto) AS branch_avg;
```

Also start using `INNER JOIN` instead of old style comma separated join

Comment: Aggregation without a `group by` clause?  I think we need more information before we can answer this question.

Comment: @sgeddes - I believe he wants to find the maximum average. Updated

Comment: Perhaps, not really sure until OP updates the question.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'll use INNER JOIN from now on (Yes, I wanted to find the max average and the branch it corresponds to).

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, an AS clause on a subquery cannot assign column names (and it is not needed in the first place).

To rename the output columns of a (sub)query, you must use AS in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT branch_no,
       max(avg_salary) AS avg_salary
FROM (...);
```

Answer (score 0):

assume the version of SQL Server is 2008 R2,

```
select branch_no, max (avg_salary)
from (select allocatedto, avg (salary)
      from staff, worker
      where staff.staff_no = worker.staff_no
      group by allocatedto) 
    as branch_avg (branch_no, avg_salary)
group by branch_no;
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `sqlite` not `sql-server`